# Configuration for spice-vdagentd

Tags: systemd, spice

In a systemd config file `/lib/systemd/system/spice-vdagent.service` I found variable `SPICE_VDAGENTD_EXTRA_ARGS`.

Where can I set the value of this variable?

I'm working on a workaround for bug [1633609](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/spice-vdagent/+bug/1633609?comments=all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new empty file under `/etc/default/` and name it `spice-vdagentd` (e.g `/etc/default/spice-vdagentd`). Then put a single assignment to variable `SPICE_VDAGENTD_EXTRA_ARGS` into this file that contains any of `spice-vdagentd`'s command line options. For example I put `-X` into that file.

Example:

```
SPICE_VDAGENTD_EXTRA_ARGS=-X
```

I have tried this under the current Ubuntu 17.04 which is not yet release, so I cannot say if it will work in older versions.

Comment: Works like charm in Ubuntu 16.10.  Thanks!

Comment: Works also in Ubuntu 17.04.